# Free dynamically allocated memory from 2D array within a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, multidimensional-array

I have a pointer to a struct and one of the objects in the struct is a int **. The double pointer is used to dynamically allocate memory for a 2d array. I am having trouble figuring out how to free the memory for this array. Any ideas?

```
struct time_data {
    int *week;
    int *sec;
    int **date;
};
typedef struct time_data time_data;

time_data *getTime(time_data *timeptr, int rows, int cols) {
    int i = 0;
    time_data time;

    // allocate memory for time.date field
    time.date = (int **)malloc(rows*(sizeof(int *))); // allocate rows
    if(time.date == NULL)
        printf("Out of memory\n");
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        time.date[i] = (int *)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
        if(time.date[i] == NULL)
            printf("Out of memory\n");
    }
    timeptr = &time;
    return timeptr;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    time_data *time = NULL;
    int rows = 43200, cols = 6;
    int i;
    time = getTime(time, rows, cols);

    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
        free(time->date[i]); // problem here
    free(time->date);

}
```

Modified Version (in case anyone else has similar issue)

```
    struct time_data {
    int *week;
    int *sec;
    int **date;
};
typedef struct time_data time_data;

time_data *getTime(int rows, int cols) {
    int i = 0;
    time_data *time = malloc(sizeof(*time));

    // allocate memory for time.date field
    time->date = (int **)malloc(rows*(sizeof(int *))); // allocate rows
    if(time->date == NULL)
        printf("Out of memory\n");

    for(i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        time->date[i] = (int *)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
        if(time->date[i] == NULL)
            printf("Out of memory\n");
    }
    return time;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    time_data *time = NULL;
    int rows = 43200, cols = 6;
    int i;
    time = getTime(rows, cols);

    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
        free(time->date[i]); // problem here
    free(time->date);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: What ideas? you are doing it right. Just remove the cast from malloc. And also, `printf("Out of memory\n");` is not enough, you shold abort and not dereferene the pointer.

Comment: You're freeing it correctly. But you're not allocating it correctly. `getTime` is returning the address of a local variable, which is not valid.

Comment: Why do I want to remove the cast from malloc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your freeing is ok, but you have a severe error

```
timeptr = &time;
return timeptr;
```

you are returning the address of a local variable.

The local variable is allocated in the stack frame of the function, and once the function returns, the data will no longer exist.

You should use `malloc` for that too

```
timeptr = malloc(sizeof(*timeptr));
```

and also you must return an `int` from `main()`

Comment: I changed the code to malloc the memory for the pointer but I am still getting the same error when I try to free the memory in main. Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address 0x0). If I remove the for loop everything runs fine. Correct me if I'm wrong, put I think I'm returning the address to the 2D array that I allocated. timeptr is just used to store that address until it can be returned. Do I need to malloc memory for the entire struct time, instead of doing it for a particular field?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I changed the input arguments for getTime and got rid the time_data time declaration and just used the pointer to the struct. Had to change all references to fields to time->date format. Seems to be working now